# Is there a better way of getting the profile image of the currently logged in user with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm trying to create an element that will contain the user's username and profile image. So far I've come up with a solution that works but I would like to know if there's any better options.

My solution:

```
<li>
    <img src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/".Auth::user()-
    >profile_picture)}}'>
    <p>{{ Auth::user()->username }}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Yup this will call the DB each time, if you're using this only in one place there is no problem, but if in more than one place, you should consider putting the profile picture url in session.

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't run functions in your view. Instead, send data from controller and then use in the view file.

Comment: It won't call DB each time. The authenticated user is saved for the duration of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest writing a function or an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in user model instead.

Something like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function profileImagePath()
    {
        return url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/" . $this->profile_picture);
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
<img src='{{auth()->user()->profileImagePath()}}'>
```

Comment: Is this better performance-wise? It definitely looks clearer.

Comment: It's not better performance wise, it's just easier to maintain. But performance shouldn't be an issue - you don't perform an additional query every time you call `auth()->user()` like someone commented earlier.